# How to let viewers upload images HTML

Tags: html

I was wondering what the html code was to let users upload their images to my html webpage, I looked at https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp but when i enter it, it does not work, so if anyone has a code, preferably without a php file required, please share it with me. Thx!

Comment: What code do you have already? What have you tried and what went wrong? We don't write your code for you here, just help you with it.

Comment: "preferably without a php file required" — You have to have some kind of program  running on the server to process the HTTP request. There are lots of options that are not PHP, but you should specify which are acceptable rather then just ruling one out

Answer (score -2):

In order for users to be able to upload images to your website, there needs to be a place for those images to be placed. This is the role of the your server. In the example above, they are using a php server to keep track of the image that was uploaded, and serve it back to the user when requested. So, while you may have followed the code in the example, without a server, users cannot upload anything to your site.

Comment: The OP is asking for code, so unless you want to write out their scripts for them it's not answerable (not sure about you, but spending *hours* writing code for someone usually has a $ per hour tag...)